# Can I be bound by a void contract?

Tags: united-states, contract-law

Recently, I got hold of a contract with a rather strange term:

> I understand that this document is written to be as broad and inclusive as legally permitted by the State of California. I agree that if any portion is held invalid or unenforceable, I will continue to be bound by the remaining terms.

How is this actually possible? How can I be bound by a contract that's been found to be invalid? And, by proxy, how can I actually escape a contract like this?

For reference, [this](https://www.csuchico.edu/wildcatwelcome/documents/Release%20of%20Liability%20beChico%20FL15.pdf) is a version very similar to the contract that I have a copy of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saying if part of the contract is found to be void or unenforceable, that the rest of it is still a contract.

It's called [severability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severability).

Comment: +1. Ah. I see now. Thanks and sorry for my noob question. Will accept in 5m.